# How to keep the type of each element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which I want to keep the type of each element of this array

```
const arr = ['123', '456', 789]; 
// 123 and 256 are string, 789 a number
```

I would like this result:

```
const arr2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 7, 8, 9];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a simple array reduce will suit you ?

```js
const arr = ['123', '456', 789]; 

const arr2 = arr.reduce((a,c)=>
  {
  if (Number.isInteger(c)) [ ...c.toString(10)].forEach(n=>a.push(Number(n)))
  else a.push(...c)
  return a
  },[])

document.write ( JSON.stringify( arr2 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
var arr = ['123', '456', 789];
var result = arr.flatMap((val=> Number.isFinite(val) ? [...val.toString()].map(k=>parseInt(k)) : [...val.toString()]));

console.log(result);
```

This will do the trick. I hope it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do it by 'reduce' method of array. btw, you can do it the same way with a map method. 
when you iterate array of items, you can check it's type. 
i converted every incoming value in string, because this is way to get every single symbol for the new results array.
then according it's type i create new array using rest operator and returns it with accumulator in the loop.

```js
const arr = ["123", "456", 789]; // 123 and 256 are string, 789 a number

const arr2 = arr.reduce((acc, rec) => {
  let data = rec + "";
  let newArr = data.split("");
  if (typeof rec === "string") {
    newArr = newArr.map((it) => it);
    return [...acc, ...newArr];
  }
  let num = newArr.map((it) => +it);
  return [...acc, ...num];
}, []);

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it was for 2 reasons: We prefer the poster to try to solve the problem first, and you didn't provide any explanation about how it works.

Comment: i thought that code is clear to understand, but if you think it's not enough - i will edit my post! :)

Comment: I've been programming for >40 years, and I still find clever uses of `reduce()` unclear. It will be totally over the head of newbies.

Comment: i looked author's profile - it seems hi is not kind of newbie. reduce - is the powerful method of transforming array data. of course, we can use map method here or 'classic' for-loops, but it will be important to keep pace with modern language opportunities. anyway, i add comments to code, hope it will be helpful for someone. thanks for your attention to this code and post!

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ['123', '456', 789];

const arr2 = arr
    .map(itemToParse => {
        const isString = typeof itemToParse === 'string';

        const stringItemToParse = String(itemToParse);
        const stringChunks = stringItemToParse.split('');

        return stringChunks.map(chunk =>
            isString ?
                chunk :
                parseInt(chunk))
    })
    .flat();

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ["123", "456", 786];
const newArr = [];

arr.forEach(elem => {
  if (typeof elem == 'number') {
    elem.toString().split('').forEach(ele => {
      newArr.push(parseInt(ele));
    })
  } else {
    elem.split('').forEach(ele => {
      newArr.push(ele);
    })
  }
})

console.log(newArr) // ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 7, 8, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ['123', '456', 789];
result = [];

function convertType (type,value){
    switch(type){
        case 'string':
            return String(value);
        break;
        case 'number':
            return Number(value);
        break;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var type = typeof(arr[i]);  
    var split = (arr[i] + '').split('').map((i) => { return Number(i); })
    for(item of split){
        var converted =  convertType(type,item);        
        result.push(converted)
    }   

}
console.log(result);
```